# How to java Program to Check if an array contains a given two different values?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to write a code to check the existence of given two values in a List.

```
List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

The requirement is to return `true` only if the List `tag` contains both `"start"` and `"end"` values.
My code is like this, but it doesn't cater to the requirement.

```
public static boolean checkStartAndEndTimeTag(List<Tag> tags) {
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        int count = 0;
        for (Tag tag : tags) {
            if (tag.getKey().equals("start") || tag.getKey().equals("end")) {
                count++;
                if (count == 2)
                    break;
                isSuccess = true;
            }

        }
        return isSuccess;
```

Can someone help me with to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
if (count == 2)
  break;
isSuccess = true;
```

doesn't make sense.  This will set `isSuccess` even if there is only one match

## The long winded approach

Okay, let's assuming for a second that you only care if there is at least one `start` and one `end` (discounting duplicates).  One approach would be to use to state flags, one for `start` and one for `end`.  To keep it simple, they would start of as `0` but would only ever be a maximum of `1` (because we don't want duplicates), then you might be able to do something like...

```
public static boolean checkStartAndEndTimeTag(List<Tag> tags) {
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    int starts = 0;
    int ends = 0;
    for (Tag tag : tags) {
        if (tag.getKey().equals("start")) {
            starts = 1;
        } else if (tag.getKey().equals("end")) {
            ends = 1;
        }
    }
    isSuccess = (starts + ends) == 2;
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Ok, you don't need `isSuccess = (starts + ends) == 2;` and could simply `return` the result of the comparison.  You could also break out of the loop if `(starts + ends) == 2` and save yourself from unnecessary computation

```
for (Tag tag : tags) {
    if (tag.getKey().equals("start")) {
        starts = 1;
    } else if (tag.getKey().equals("end")) {
        ends = 1;
    }

    if ((starts + ends) == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

## Using streams...

One approach might be to make use the streams support and simply `filter` the `List` and `count` the results, for example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>(25);
        tags.add(new Tag("begin"));
        tags.add(new Tag("front"));
        tags.add(new Tag("start"));
        tags.add(new Tag("finish"));
        tags.add(new Tag("tail"));
        tags.add(new Tag("end"));

        boolean isSuccessful = tags.stream().filter(tag -> tag.getKey().equals("start") || tag.getKey().equals("end")).count() >= 2;
        System.out.println(isSuccessful);
    }

    public class Tag {
        private String key;

        public Tag(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }


    }
}
```

## Updated...

Okay, this got complicated fast.  Let's assume you don't want to match two `start` tags, so you MUST have both one `end` and one `start` tag

So, using the above, example, we can modify the `Tag` class to support `equals` (and by extension `hashcode`)

```
public class Tag {

    private String key;

    public Tag(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.key);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Tag other = (Tag) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.key, other.key)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then we can simply use `distinct` to filter out any duplicates, for example...

```
boolean isSuccessful = tags
        .stream()
        .distinct()
        .filter(tag -> tag.getKey().equals("start") || tag.getKey().equals("end"))
        .count() >= 2;
```

Probably not the most efficient solution, but certainly one of the shortest

Answer (score 2):

In this code

```
if (tag.getKey().equals("start") || tag.getKey().equals("end")) {
     count++;
     if (count == 2)
            break;
     isSuccess = true;
}
```

you are setting `isSuccess` to true whenever the `tag` is `start` or `end`.

Better way would be

```
if (tag.getKey().equals("start") || tag.getKey().equals("end")) {
    count++;
    if (count == 2)
        return true;
}
```

Comment: That would erroneously return true if the array contains "start" twice.

Comment: I just realized that mistake was in the original code to begin with...

Comment: @daniu Furthermore it erroneously return true if the array contains "end" twice - yeah I noticed this when writing the question but forgot to mention.

Comment: Okay! It works fine. I set `isSuccess = true` inside if loop and return isSuccess out of the for loop. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
tags.stream()
    .map(Tag::getKey)
    .distinct()
    .filter(t -> "start".equals(t) || "end".equals(t))
    .count() == 2;
```

This would also fix the issue that your original code falsely returns true if the list contains statt or end twice.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried your code against the test data from my answer (`[begin, front, start, finish, tail, start]`) and it returns `true` ... I might be doing something wrong though and it returns `false` for `[begin, front, start, finish, tail, start, end]`

Comment: Oddly, `System.out.println("Map = " + tags.stream().map(Tag::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()));` will print `Map = [begin, front, start, finish, tail, start, end]` which doesn't seem to be removing the duplicates - maybe it's my `equals`/`hashcode` methods?

Comment: You should call `distinct` after `map` tho remove the duplicate strings

Comment: if the list after `map` contains 3 or more duplicate of either "start" or "end" and not the other, using `> 2` still return true.

Comment: It's Friday and it seems to show for us all  accepted @HaiHoang s edit with `distinct`.

Comment: @daniu , seem true, you should edit it again because the correct getter is `Tag::getKey` 

Answer (score -2):

What about

```
tags.containsAll(Arrays.asList(new Tag("start"), new Tag("stop")))
```

Comment: (Not a downvoted) The original `List` doesn't contain `String`s, it contains a `Tag` object - whose implementation we don't know